# correct syntax for use of file descriptors with imagemagick

Tags: bash, imagemagick, file-descriptors

According to the [ImageMagick manual](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php), file descriptors are supported as of v.6.4.9-3. I am running v.6.9.7-4. However, I have been able to determine the correct syntax. Examples tried:

```
convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' fd:3 ;       display fd:3
convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' miff:fd:3 ;  display fd:3
convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' miff: fd:3 ; display fd:3
convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' miff:fd:3 ;  display miff:fd:3
```

The error produced by the first and second commands is as follows:

```
convert-im6.q16: no encode delegate for this image format `FD' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1176.
display-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
display-im6.q16: no data returned `3' @ error/fd.c/ReadFDImage/123.
```

The third command causes the terminal to hang but eventually produces the same error message as the first two commands. The fourth command produces the following error:

```
Aborted
display-im6.q16: improper image header `/tmp/magick-7315YQugjYiINA9c' @ error/miff.c/ReadMIFFImage/507.
```

The redirection can be accomplished using native bash file descriptors instead of ImageMagick's cross-platform implementation thereof; e.g.,

```
exec 3> myfifo ; convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' miff:- 1>&3 ; exec 3>&-; exec 3< myfifo; display - 0<&3 ; exec 3<&- ; rm myfifo
```

or

```
exec 3> myfifo ; convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' miff:- 1>&3 ; exec 3>&-; exec 3< myfifo; display <&3 ; exec 3<&- ; rm myfifo
```

However, that is much longer to write and is also not cross-platform, so I am hoping to be able to figure out ImageMagick's file descriptor syntax.

My intent is to be able to read from multiple fds for a convert command, for instance:

```
<upstream commands> | convert - fd:3 -append | <downstream commands>
```

Edit:

I was able to use the following hybrid approach:

```
exec 3> myfifo ; convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' miff:- 1>&3 ; exec 3>&-; exec 3< myfifo; display fd:3 ; exec 3<&- ; rm myfifo
```

Trying to write to `fd:3`, however, does not work:

```
exec 3> myfifo ; convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' miff:fd:3 ; exec 3>&-; exec 3< myfifo; display fd:3 ; exec 3<&- ; rm myfifo
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Any error message? Is the resulting image corrupted or in the wrong format? I have no problem to have `convert` (IM 6.8) read or write to fds.

Comment: `miff:fd:3` produces a file of length 0 for me (6.9.2-7), but `gif:fd:3` and `jpg:fd:3` work ok, so it might be a bug for some image formats.

Comment: @xhienne : I added error message information to the post.

Comment: @meuh : The command also fails when I try other formats (e.g., `convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' gif:fd:3`; the error message is simply `Aborted`).

Comment: I agree with meuh, this seems like a bug. `convert 'xc:white[100x100!]' png:fd:10 10> /tmp/foo.png` works well for me. OTOH, with jpg and miff, only stdout (i.e. `jpeg:-` or `miff:-`) is actually working. As for your Aborted error message, I get this when my fd is not opened for writing.